# How do i add the equality operator to ImageButton (JUCE)?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, juce

i have a few imagebuttons with their respective buttonListeners.

on the buttonClicked function i try to:

```
void TestComponent::buttonClicked (Button* activeButton) {

    if (activeButton == typeButton) {

       //do something

    }

}
```

But i get

```
"No match for operator == in activeButton..."
```

How can i add the parent class Button equality operator to ImageButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activeButton is a pointer. What is typeButton?

Comment: typeButton is an ImageButton which inherits from Button: http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/api/classImageButton.html

Comment: Please include a larger code snippet that contains the declaration of typeButton.